# React.PropTypes is deprecated and I have installed prop-types package

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-proptypes

I am following a React tutorial [here](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-introduction-to-properties). In the fourth lesson it has me create a `App.propTypes` section. When I run the code React gives me a error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined` when I open up my console the error says `React.PropTypes is deprecated since React 15.5.0, use the npm module prop-types instead`. I then went ahead and installed the npm package [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) and imported it in my code, but I still end up with the same error. I will include my code below.

I am using node version *v8.5.0*. Maybe I should try and find out what version of node the tutorial is using so my React version matches up, but I don't even know if I can find that out, I wish tutorials would specify these sorts of things, it looks like this tutorial is 2 years old, which is probably why I am having this discrepancy.

**src/app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    let txt = this.props.txt
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{txt}</h1>
        <b>bold</b>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  txt: React.PropTypes.string,
  cat: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired
}

export default App;
```

**/src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App cat={5} txt="this is the prop value" />, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: `txt: React.PropTypes.string` => `txt: PropTypes.string`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
txt: React.PropTypes.string,
cat: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired
```

to

```
txt: PropTypes.string,
cat: PropTypes.number.isRequired
```

You have PropTypes imported as PropTypes from 'prop-types' so there is no need to use PropTypes as a property of React.  Using PropTypes as a property of React was deprecated a few months ago.

Also, you have cat marked as isRequired but do not use it anywhere in your App component. So that will display a lint error.

Other than that, I'm not sure what the issue is.  I ran your source code on my machine and it came out ok.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the prop-types package, you can do this:

```
App.propTypes = {
  txt: PropTypes.string,
  cat: PropTypes.number.isRequired
}
```

Also, the error your getting is because you don't have cat coming in anywhere as props yet.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same tutorial and resolved it by doing the following.

**part 1**

- Prop-Types install

  1. `sudo npm -i -g prop-types`
  2. in App.js

     - ensure `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';` is on top of file.
  3. Change

     `App.propTypes = {
     txt: React.PropTypes.string,
     cat: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired
     }`

     to

     `App.propTypes = {
     txt: PropTypes.string,//------------ remove React
     cat: PropTypes.number.isRequired//-- remove React
     }`

**part 2**

- Reinstall node_modules

  1. delete package-**lock**.json NOT package.json
  2. run `sudo npm install`
  3. `npm start`

Ref. https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

Ref. https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2534

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you need to use this package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types)